# The intersection of infinite and finite closed and bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

*Question*:
Let $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are both closed and bounded. Prove that if $\cap_{k=1}^{n}A_k \neq \emptyset$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$, then $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k \neq \emptyset$.

*Proof*: 
If $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k = \emptyset$, then for all $x \in \cap_{k=1}^{l}A_k$, $x \notin A_j$ where $l \lt j$ for some $ l,j\in \mathbb N$. Then $\cap_{k=1}^{j}A_k = \emptyset$.

Is that correct? If it is, then how does the property that each $A_k$ being closed and bounded play into the proof? I'm guessing it does, in some subtle way, and that the proof doesn't hold for open and unbounded sets? Also, counter-examples?

Comment: Not in the least bit correct.  To begin with you are assuming something that you specifically was told was not true so nothing you conclude will have any relevance.  Second your conclusion has utterly no basis whatsoever and isn't at all true.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I intended to do a contrapositive.

Comment: Then the n needs to be infinity.  But in no way does x not in A_j for l <j follow.

Comment: @fleablood Corrected it now.

Comment: @fleablood, Okay, then what strategy do I use?

Comment: A counter example of your argument is $A_n=(0,1/n) $.  No finite intersection is empty but the infinite intersection is.  Closed sets contain their limit points.  Consider sup and inf of $\cap_n A_n $ as the intersections are closed bounded and nested ....

Comment: @fleablood Just one final (really simple) question. Is it always the case that sequences of subsets are nested?

Comment: It is not necessary that the sets $A_{n} $ are nested, but as you can see their intersection $B_{n} =\cap_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}$ form a nested sequence of closed and bounded subsets and by Cantor Intersection Theorem there is a point $x$ which lies in all $B_{n} $ and hence in all $A_{n} $. Thus the result in your question is a simple corollary of Cantor intersection theorem. Cantor Intersection Theorem itself is based on completeness of real numbers and is proved in most analysis textbooks.

Comment: I didn't say the $A_n$ were nested (which of course they don't need to be)  I said the $\cap_{k=1}^nA_k$ were nested (actually I screwed up the typing, sorry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to construct a sequence. For every $n$ take some $x_n \in \bigcap_{k=1}^nA_k$, which is non-empty. The Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem then says that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x^*$.

As $x_{n_k} \in A_1$ for all $k$, and because $A_1$ is closed (and therefore contains all its limit points), $x^*\in A_1$.
Indeed, as the finite intersection of closed sets is always closed, $x^* \in \bigcap_{k=1}^nA_k$, and it follows that

$$x^* \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$$

*Note* that the boundedness of the sequence follows from boundedness on each $\bigcap_{k=1}^nA_k$. If we want to be more specific, suppose $M_n$ is a sequence such that $|f(x)|\leq M_n$ on $\bigcap_{k=1}^nA_k$, then $M_{n}\geq M_{n+1}$ and in particular, $|f(x_k)| \leq M_k \leq M_1$ for all $k$.